# swiftmailer and Yii2 not working 1 out of 10 time

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I have a background process sending email to me when specific event occur. 
It's working most of the time (9 out of 10), but sometime I get the following error message :

```
PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'fwrite(): SSL: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.'

in E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:232

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'fwrite(): SSL: ...', 'E:\ProgramData\...', 232, Array)
#1 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(232): fwrite(Resource id #481, 'MAIL FROM:<MTE@...')
#2 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\AbstractFilterableInputStream.php(171): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_commit('MAIL FROM:<MTE@...')
#3 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\AbstractFilterableInputStream.php(90): Swift_ByteStream_AbstractFilterableInputStream->_doWrite('MAIL FROM:<MTE@...')
#4 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(276): Swift_ByteStream_AbstractFilterableInputStream->write('MAIL FROM:<MTE@...')
#5 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(243): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM:<MTE@...', Array, Array)
#6 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(322): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM:<MTE@...', Array)
#7 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(416): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doMailFromCommand('MTE@...')
#8 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message), 'MTE@...', Array, Array)
#9 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(176): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_sendTo(Object(Swift_Message), 'MTE@...', Array, Array)
#10 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(85): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#11 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-swiftmailer\Mailer.php(146): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message))
#12 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMailer.php(260): yii\swiftmailer\Mailer->sendMessage(Object(yii\swiftmailer\Message))
#13 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMessage.php(48): yii\mail\BaseMailer->send(Object(yii\swiftmailer\Message))
#14 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\controllers\BackgroundTask.php(172): yii\mail\BaseMessage->send()
#15 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\bazilio\yii2-async\commands\AsyncWorkerCommand.php(29): app\controllers\BackgroundTask->execute()
#16 [internal function]: bazilio\async\commands\AsyncWorkerCommand->actionDaemon('background')
#17 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(151): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#19 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(91): yii\base\Controller->runAction('daemon', Array)
#20 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\console\Controller->runAction('daemon', Array)
#21 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(167): yii\base\Module->runAction('async-worker/da...', Array)
#22 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(143): yii\console\Application->runAction('async-worker/da...', Array)
#23 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#24 E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\yii(23): yii\base\Application->run()
#25 {main}
PHP Warning:  fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry in E:\ProgramData\htdocs\Yii2_KB\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 232
```

Here follow my configuration for the mailer :

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'x.x.x.xxx',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'XyXyXy',
            'port' => '25',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],

    ],
```

I'm using Yii 2.0.6
PHP Version : 5.5.9
Mail server : Exchange Server 2010

When it fail, it's mostly after a period of inactivity between 2 events ( a few hours).

Any ideas ?

Comment: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/696

Comment: is there any extra informations into your server log files ? it may be similar to this [socket error](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_299.asp).

Comment: It's caused by SSL, after opening socket - sending message, at some time(~60 seconds for me) ssl connection will go into timeout. To resume it you should use exactly the same parameters as last write, but they are already changed. So if you not sending emails for some time, before send you should do `transport->stop()` and then start. It should reopen socket and fix problem.

Comment: I modified my code and added `transport->stop()`. Seem to do the trick. I will wait until tomorrow to give more news

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ineersa for the tips.

I've added  the following code in the beginning of the background process, and now it's working.

```
        if (Yii::$app->mailer->getTransport()->isStarted()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->getTransport()->stop();
        }
        Yii::$app->mailer->getTransport()->start();
```