# Is my yii2 smtp configuration correct?

Tags: yii2

I have the following smtp configuration, but I'm not sure since sometimes I face ssl timed out while sending an email.

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => true,
],

'mail' => [
'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
'viewPath' => '@backend/mail',
'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
//comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
'transport' => [
    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    'host' => 'in-v3.mailjet.com',
    'username' => 'a3027c3xxx',
    'password' => 'c838779xxx',
    'port' => '465',
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
],
],
```

Then I use like this

```
$message = Yii::$app->mail->compose();
$message->setTo(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
->setTo("mymail@gmail.com")
->setSubject('Password Reset')
->setHtmlBody($this->renderAjax('//email/_konten',['hello'=>"To black" ,'konten'=>'this is konten','link'=>Yii::$app->params['baseurl'].'lupapass/chpass?&q=empty','textbutton'=>'Click this link']))
->send();
```

and the result is sometime I face timed out.

But if I send directly from swiftmailler class like below code it sucessfully send 100 email without any ssl timed out

```
$transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('in-v3.mailjet.com', 465)
->setUsername('myusername')
->setPassword('s3cr3t')
->setEncryption('ssl');

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('Password Reset')
  ->setFrom(array('no-reply@myweb.com' => 'My Web'))
  ->setTo(array('some@one.com'))
  ->setBody($this->renderAjax('//email/_konten',['hello'=>"To black" ,'konten'=>'this is konten','link'=>Yii::$app->params['baseurl'].'lupapass/chpass?&q=empty','textbutton'=>'Click this link']))
  ->setContentType("text/html")
  ;
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

If you ask how my ssl timed out here is my question link

[How to solve Swift_TransportException Connection to ssl Timed Out error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918420/how-to-solve-swift-transportexception-connection-to-ssl-timed-out-error)

So I start thinking is this ssl timed out because my configuration? or different sending method? from first example and second example?

in `common\config\main-local.php` there is a `mailer => []` and `mail => []` is this neccessary?

an can you please explain what is `useFileTransport` really?

Thanks in advance.

PS. I have already use any thirdparty and port configuration but still facing ssl timed out issue.

Comment: Have you got any solution. I have same issue like you. Using directly from swift mailer it works. but not sending message default value.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Gmail SMTP config](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) when you are using encryption `ssl` or `tls` use port `587` instead of `465`